# Undefined Method in my service objects module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wanted to clean up and refactor a bit the code of my create method inside my orders controller, and I read that is a good practice to use service objects. Starting from this horrible code here:

```
def create
  if current_user.orders.where(paid: false).present?
    order = current_user.orders.last
    order_id = order.id
    product_id = @product.id
    @product.ordinable = false
    @product.save
    order_amount = order.amount
    if order.products << @product
      order.products.each do |x|
        @order_amountnew = order_amount + x.price
      end
      order.amount = @order_amountnew
      order.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to products_path, notice: 'Product added to the cart!' }
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to products_path, notice: 'There was a problem while adding the product to the cart!' }
      end
    end
  else
    product_id = @product.id
    order = current_user.orders.new
    order.save
    order_id = order.id
    @product.ordinable = false
    @product.save
    order_amount = order.amount
    if order.products << @product
      order.products.each do |x|
        @order_amountnew = order_amount + x.price
      end
      order.amount = @order_amountnew
      order.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to products_path, notice: 'Product added to the cart!' }
      end
      OrderPaidCheckJob.set(wait: 3.minutes).perform_later(order_id)
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to products_path, notice: 'There was a problem while adding the product to the cart!' }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

i wanted to split the method in two segments basically so i created two modules in the services folder as follow.
I called the first one order_present_create_service

```
module OrderPresentCreateService
  class << self
    def create(params)
      order = current_user.orders.last
      order_id = order.id
      product_id = @product.id
      @product.ordinable = false
      @product.save
      order_amount = order.amount
      if order.products << @product
        order.products.each do |x|
          @order_amountnew = order_amount + x.price
        end
        order.amount = @order_amountnew
        order.save
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to products_path, notice: 'Product added to the cart!' }
        end
      else
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to products_path, notice: 'There was a problem while adding the product to the cart!' }
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and i called the second one order_new_create_service

```
module OrderNewCreateService
  class << self
    def create(params)
      product_id = params[:id]
      order = current_user.orders.new
      order.save
      order_id = order.id
      @product.ordinable = false
      @product.save
      order_amount = order.amount
      if order.products << @product
        order.products.each do |x|
          @order_amountnew = order_amount + x.price
        end
        order.amount = @order_amountnew
        order.save
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to products_path, notice: 'Product added to the cart!' }
        end
        OrderPaidCheckJob.set(wait: 3.minutes).perform_later(order_id)
      else
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to products_path, notice: 'There was a problem while adding the product to the cart!' }
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

here my new controller:

```
def create
  if current_user.orders.where(paid: false).present?
    OrderPresentCreateService.create(params)
  else
    OrderNewCreateService.create(params)
  end
end
```

I was simply following this article [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/service-objects-explained-simply-for-ruby-on-rails-5-a8cc42a5441f) to make it works.
When i try to create an order, now i get this error:

> undefined local variable or method `current_user' for OrderNewCreateService:Module

At the beginning i was getting a similar error with product_id = @product.id, so i changed it in product_id = params[:id] and i make it work somehow. Where am i doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you can refactor your `create` action without using services. (I'm a huge fan of services. I just don't think you need them here.)

First, I would add a couple of methods to your User model, something like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  def unpaid_orders
    orders.where(paid: false)
  end

  def unpaid_orders?
    unpaid_orders.any?
  end

end
```

Then, I would make `amount` a method instead of an attribute, something like:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord 

  def amount
    products.sum(&:price)
  end

end
```

Then, in your controller, you can do something like:

```
delegate *%w(
  unpaid_orders?
  orders
), to: :current_user

def create
  order = unpaid_orders? ? orders.last : orders.create!
  @product.update(ordinable: false)
  if order.products << @product 
    @notice = 'Product added to the Cart!'
    OrderPaidCheckJob.set(wait: 3.minutes).perform_later(order.id) unless unpaid_orders?
  else 
    @notice = 'There was a problem while adding the product to the cart!'
  end
  redirect_to products_path, notice: @notice
end
```

If you don't want to make `amount` a method on `Order`, then you can do:

```
delegate *%w(
  unpaid_orders?
  orders
), to: :current_user

def create
  order = unpaid_orders? ? orders.last : orders.create!
  @product.update(ordinable: false)
  if order.products << @product 
    order.update(amount: order.products.sum(&:price))
    @notice = 'Product added to the Cart!'
    OrderPaidCheckJob.set(wait: 3.minutes).perform_later(order.id) unless unpaid_orders?
  else 
    @notice = 'There was a problem while adding the product to the cart!'
  end
  redirect_to products_path, notice: @notice
end
```

Comment: In the first solution, did you forget to implement the method amount right? If so can you show me how'd you call it. About the delegate, i kinda understood what it does reading other examples, but in this case, I'm a bit confused. The primary scope of it is just to avoid a repetition to write current_user.unpaid_orders and just unpaid_orders and orders.last right? I' trying to understand it following this basic example i found here https://coderwall.com/p/wamyow/using-delegate-in-rails

Comment: And is it a good practice to just put that delegate there? Shouldn't be inside a model? Thank you

Comment: In the first approach, you don't calculate and set `amount` on order. Instead you created `amount` as an instance method on the `Order` class. Then, you can all it whenever you like (for instance `@order.amount`) and the amount will be calculated based on the current `@order.products`.

Comment: And, yes, the primary purpose of the `delegate` method (in this specific case) is just to tidy up the code. Instead of `order = unpaid_orders? ? orders.last : orders.create!`, you could do `order = current_user.unpaid_orders? ? current_user.orders.last : current_user.orders.create!`. So, it's just cosmetic.

Comment: `delegate` does not need to be inside a model. It can go in any ruby class. This example should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, the task is to refactor original action from the controller. Your refactored code has a list of problems, so to keep answer shorter let me skip reviewing it and focus on original action.

The problems I see are:

- `product_id` variable is initialized but not used
- `order_id` variable in 1st branch of `if` condition is initialized but not used
- `respond_to` block has condition for `html` format only. Since there is no code for other formats, it can be simplified
- `OrderPaidCheckJob.set` method is placed after `redirect_to`, so it will never be called. To make it work, place it before `redirect_to`
- Despite conditions of `if`, the action ends with `redirect_to` to the same path, only `notice` changes. So you could just set up right `notice`, and move `redirect_to` out of `if`s
- `@product.ordinable = false; @product.save` can be simplified as `@product.update(ordinable: false)`. Since it is in both branches of `if`, it can be moved out of that block.
- Not sure why `if order.products << @product`. When do you think this condition is falsey? In case of a problem adding it to the database, it will throw an exception.
- `order.products.each do |x|` etc block can be simplified as `order.amount = @order_amountnew = order_amount + order.products.last.price` (I suspect you have an error here because you iterate over `products` but save the result for the last product only)
- you initialize instance variable `@order_amountnew` but do not use it later because of redirect. It can be removed I think

Preliminary result:

```
def create
  @product.update(ordinable: false)

  if current_user.orders.where(paid: false).present?
    order = current_user.orders.last
    order_amount = order.amount
    if order.products << @product
      order.amount = @order_amountnew = order_amount + order.products.last.price
      order.save

      notice = 'Product added to the cart!'
    else
      notice = 'There was a problem while adding the product to the cart!'
    end

  else
    order = current_user.orders.new
    order.save
    order_id = order.id
    order_amount = order.amount
    if order.products << @product
      order.amount = @order_amountnew = order_amount + order.products.last.price
      order.save

      OrderPaidCheckJob.set(wait: 3.minutes).perform_later(order_id)

      notice = 'Product added to the cart!'
    else
      notice = 'There was a problem while adding the product to the cart!'
    end
  end

  redirect_to products_path, notice: notice
end
```

Looks better and more readable? Since it still has the repeating code it can be DRYed even more. But I would recommend managing with problems I pointed out before refactoring it further.